# Do I need the colon in the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation

> So she just looked from the outside: at the shelves with clay cups and
>   vases aligned like runners on their marks; at the pottery wheels
>   lining the table in the middle like people in a meeting; at the table
>   itself, dark like the stage of a canceled show.

Do I need the colon at the beginning of the sentence? Why or why not?

Comment: You need either that or the more modern equivalent here, the dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe no rule would require punctuation, especially a colon, in that sentence. There's no reason in fact to break the phrase "looked at" apart  -- "she just looked ... at the shelves..."

The colon makes the sentence stumble. Also, commas could be used instead of the semicolons.

"From the outside she just looked at the shelves with clay cups and vases aligned like runners on their marks, at the pottery wheels lining the table in the middle like people at a meeting, at the table itself, dark like the stage of a canceled show."

By the way, that's a lot of metaphors and imagery in one sentence -- there's a race, a meeting, and a classroom. Taking readers to that many places in just one sentence risks losing them along the way.

Comment: Uh… 8356, could you run that by us again, using the kind of analysis some give to poetry?